# What is the difference between an idiom and a turn of phrase?

Tags: difference, phrase-usage, terminology

For example, I've found the phrase "to jump out of your skin" described as a turn of phrase. But why it is not an idiom? How do we tell the difference?

Answer (score 2):

It *is* an idiom - both expressions mean the same thing. You could also call it a metaphor, since a person doesn't literally 'jump out of their skin'.

Comment: An idiom is a turn of phrase with seniority.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that a turn of phrase and an idiom are terms that can be used interchangeably?

Comment: Oxford Dictionaries definition of 'turn of phrase' is : A particular or characteristic manner of expression.
Example: "an awkward turn of phrase"
Synonyms:
expression · idiom · choice of words · word · phrase · term · locution